# A simple MYSQL view to disaply info about a player and its guardians

Tags: mysql, sql, gridview, join

I need to create a view called phonelist which list each player, their guardians, the guardians phone number and the team they play in. How would I code this. All the information you need you should find below:

[image]

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
personID INT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(50),
address VARCHAR(70),
phone VARCHAR(15),
email VARCHAR(30),
year INT,
PRIMARY KEY (personID)
);

CREATE TABLE Player
(
personID INT NOT NULL,
dateOfBirth DATE,
school VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (personID),
FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES Person (personID)
);

CREATE TABLE Team
(
teamID INT NOT NULL,
tName VARCHAR(70),
ageRange VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (teamID)
);

CREATE TABLE Coach
(
personID INT NOT NULL,
dateBeganCoaching DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (personID),
FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES Person (personID)
);

CREATE TABLE coachTeam
(
personID INT NOT NULL, 
teamID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (personID, teamID),
FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES Coach (personID),
FOREIGN KEY (teamID) REFERENCES Team (teamID)
);

CREATE TABLE playerTeam
(
personID INT NOT NULL, 
teamID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (personID, teamID),
FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES Player (personID),
FOREIGN KEY (teamID) REFERENCES Team (teamID)
);

CREATE TABLE Guardian
(
parentID INT NOT NULL,
childID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (parentID, childID),
FOREIGN KEY (parentID) REFERENCES Person (personID),
FOREIGN KEY (childID) REFERENCES Person (personID)
);

CREATE TABLE Qualification
(
qualificationID INT NOT NULL,
qName VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (qualificationID)
);

CREATE TABLE coachQualification
(
qualificationID INT NOT NULL,
personID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (personID, qualificationID),
FOREIGN KEY (qualificationID) REFERENCES Qualification (qualificationID),
FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES Coach (personID)
);
```

How would I do it so that I am using only the person table to reference the player, and guardians and how would I do it so that if a player had more than one guardian both guardian would be placed on the same line as opposed to creating an entire new row in the output to dispaly both guardian thanks.

I have tried the following but have gotten errors:

```
CREATE VIEW phonelist AS 
SELECT Child.name, tName, Parent.name, Parent.phone
FROM playerTeam INNER JOIN Person AS Child ON playerTeam.personID = Child.personID
                INNER JOIN Team ON playerTeam.teamID = Team.teamID
                INNER JOIN Person AS Parent ON Guardian.parentID = Parent.personID;

Select * FROM phonelist ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Comment: @JustDanyul: Unknown column 'Guardian.parentID' in 'on clause'

Comment: sorry, i removed the comment because i spotted it before you answered :)

Comment: "and the team they play in" the team the guardian plays in or the person or both?

Comment: @xQbert: no just the team the child of the guradian plays in

Comment: Why do you keep deleting your question?  That's not how it works here.  If you don't want people to see the information permanently, then don't post it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select P.ID, P.Name, P2.PersonID, P2.Name, P2.Phone, T2.tName as GuardianTeam T.tName as PersonTeam
INNER JOIN Player PL on PL.PErsonID=P.PersonID
INNER JOIN Guardian G on G.ParentID = P.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Person P2 on P2.PersonID = G.ChildID
INNER JOIN PlayerTeam PT on PT.PersonID = PL.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Player PL2 on PL2.PersonID = P2.PersonID
LEFT JOIN PlayerTeam PT2 on PT2.PersonID = PT2.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Team T2 on T2.TeamID = PT.TeamID
INNER JOIN Team T on T.TeamID = PT.TeamID
```

Ah ok edit to remove person team...

Returns all persons who are players, their guardian name, phone and guardian team as well as any players without guardians; or instances where guardians are not part of teams, or players themselves.

```
Select P.ID, P.Name, P2.PersonID, P2.Name, P2.Phone, T2.tName as GuardianTeam
INNER JOIN Player PL on PL.PErsonID=P.PersonID
INNER JOIN Guardian G on G.ParentID = P.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Person P2 on P2.PersonID = G.ChildID
LEFT JOIN Player PL2 on PL2.PersonID = P2.PersonID
LEFT JOIN PlayerTeam PT2 on PT2.PersonID = PT2.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Team T2 on T2.TeamID = PT.TeamID
```